# I am In sudo group. Yet I can not do sudo commands

Tags: sudo

I have added myself to the sudo group. Yet when I try to perform A Sudo command, the error that says user not in sudoers group still pops up. Please help!

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  How did you add yourself and did you make sure it worked?  What does `id` show?

Comment: Even if `id` shows that the user is in `sudo`, the addition doesn't actually become effective until a new login shell is invoked (either by actually logging out/in, or spawning a login subshell e.g. `su - $USER`)